# Blank Page for JSON Obj in PHP

Tags: php, html, json

When I print out as array, It's OK, it prints, but it doesn't print as `JSON Objects`, instead, It returns blank page

Thanks in Advance

```
<?

require_once('include/db_functions.php');

if($_GET){
    $ad = stripslashes($_GET["ad"]);
    try{
        $dbFuncs = new db_functions();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print $e -> getMessage();
    }

    $ss = $dbFuncs->getCategoryLista($ad);

    foreach($ss as $ccc){
        $data[] = array(
            "ID" => $ccc['CategoryID'],
            "Name" => $ccc['CategoryName']
        );
    }        
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please use the code block in the editor when posting code. Also, your variable names do make this a bit difficult. Do any errors appear in the PHP error log?

Comment: It could be a range of things. Do you have php short tags turned on? (`<?`). Turn on error reporting at the top of your page with `<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`, and debug. Then update your question with the errors that show up.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your commets, It says;

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Why do i have to use PDO or mysqli, what do you think about it ?

Comment: Because the `mysql_*` library isn't secure anymore and is removed as of PHP7. You're best to use a library (PDO/MySQLi) that supports prepared statements, as it's more secure, SQL Injection wise.

Comment: Ok. I got it, now I have to recode more than 100 db function :/

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be blank due to different factors, in fact your code would only output the JSON if everything went fine as expected. You only coded the happy cases, you need to include all possible condition to your json:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require_once('include/db_functions.php');
$data = array();
if(isset($_GET["ad"])){
    $ad = stripslashes($_GET["ad"]);
    try{
        $dbFuncs = new db_functions();
        $ss = $dbFuncs->getCategoryLista($ad);

        if(count($ss) != 0){
            $data['success'] = true;
            foreach($ss as $ccc){
                $data['data'][] = array(
                    "ID" => $ccc['CategoryID'],
                    "Name" => $ccc['CategoryName']
                );
            }    
        }else{
            $data['success'] = false;
            $data['data'] = 'count() == 0';
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print $e -> getMessage();
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['data'] = 'error = '.$e -> getMessage();
    }
}else{
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['data'] = '$_GET["ad"] is not set';

}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```